# If a ring contains a subring, does it contain the subring's isomorphic ring??

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am new to abstract algebra and just studied subrings and morphisms, sorry if the question is dumb.
Let's say that R is a ring that contains A, and A is isomorphic to B.
Can we say that R contains B too?!
If yes, why?

Comment: No:  just take an isomorphic ring with no elements in common with $R$.

Comment: Nope, all you can say is that there is an injective ring morphism from $B\to R$.

Comment: Sometimes authors "identify" $B$ with a subring of $R$ and write everything as if $B\subset R$.

Comment: This has nothing to do with rings, really. You could ask this about sets. If a set $X$ contains a subset $Y$, and $Z$ has as many elements as $Y$, does that mean $X$ contains $Z$?

Comment: An added note is: you can then make a ring $R'$ which will be isomorphic to $R$ but contain $B$. How? Let $\phi:A\to B$ is an isomorphism. Make $R'=(R\setminus A)\cup B$ as a set, and define the operations on it in such way so that $\overline\phi$ is an isomorphism, where $\overline\phi(x)=\begin{cases}\phi(x)&x\in A\\x&x\in R\setminus A\end{cases}$. (At least this works when $R\cap B=\emptyset$; otherwise you need to employ "disjoint union" of $R\setminus A$ with $B$).